# find location of a point on a polygon or cycle in mysql

Tags: mysql, geocoding

How can i determine if a point with given (Latitude, Longitude) is inside a polygon defined by a list of (Latitude, Longitude)? 
now if i save shapes as circle defined by (Latitude, Longitude, Radius) how can i handle it?
please explain both of this scenario.... thanx

Comment: How can a polygon be a circle ?

Comment: technically, a circle is an `infinitegon`, which would fall under "poly".

Comment: @MarcB yes, but that would be a bit hard to fit in a database :)

Comment: Can we add a programming language `tag`

Comment: in any case, for a circle, you calculate distance from the point to the center of the circle. if `distance <= radius`, it's "inside". @DrewPierce: this is mysql, so... sql?

Comment: @MarcB yes, but then what do we do with the polygon. @DrewPierce `MySQL` counts as a language i guess...

Comment: cyrcle in my case is a (Latitude, Longitude) and a raduis and polygon is a list of (Latitude, Longitude)

Comment: indeed ...you are right @MarcB but what is formula in circle ....and what about polygon ....can you guide me?

Comment: You can use [this algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon#Ray_casting_algorithm), but it will be a real pain to do it in MySQL. Or if you have MySQL >= 5.6 you can convert your data to spatial datatypes and use [ST_Contains](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/spatial-relation-functions-object-shapes.html#function_st-contains). For the circle case you only need to calculate the distance between two points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A polygon is a shape with straight sides and final connection not-open. Circles need not apply. They are posers.

Brilliant edit to follow when time permits.

**Edit**:

```
create table polyThing
(
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    boundary polygon not null
);

insert polyThing (boundary)
VALUES(
PolygonFromText(
'POLYGON(( 
9.190586853 45.464518970,
9.190602686 45.463993916,
9.191572471 45.464001929,
9.191613325 45.463884676,
9.192136130 45.463880767,
9.192111509 45.464095594,
9.192427961 45.464117804,
9.192417811 45.464112862,
9.192509035 45.464225851,
9.192493139 45.464371079,
9.192448471 45.464439002,
9.192387444 45.464477861,
9.192051402 45.464483037,
9.192012814 45.464643592,
9.191640825 45.464647090,
9.191622331 45.464506215,
9.190586853 45.464518970))'
)
);

insert polyThing (boundary) 
select PolygonFromText(
"POLYGON
((
121.44842136764532 121.44842136764532,
121.45076025390631 31.221990825071376,
121.45402182006842 31.218366658611853,
121.45091045761114 31.217054584347302,
121.44842136764532 31.22119260287111
))
")

-- mysql 5.6.1 and later I believe:
select p.id, ST_Contains(p.boundary,GeomFromText('POINT(23.9999 38.224)'))
from polyThing p

-- older version
select p.id, Contains(p.boundary,GeomFromText('POINT(23.9999 38.224)'))
from polyThing p

select p.id, Contains(p.boundary,GeomFromText('POINT(121.44842136764532 121.44842136764532)'))
from polyThing p
```

GIS Spatial

Contains may or not work. Aim for 5.6.1 and above and use ST_Contains

Comment: thank you for your useful suggestion and if mysql version is lower than 5.6.1 is there a way ?